# Excel 2013 - User can't execute specific macro - File name listed before macro in Macros window

Tags: vba, excel

We have a single user unable to execute a specific macro in an XLSM file using Excel 2013.  The issue seems to be tied to the user's entitlements because he gets the same error even on a freshly imaged machine.  I would love to know if anyone has seen this issue before so we can pinpoint what's causing it internally.  This can't be replicated by any other user, but is persistent to the user's account on any PC.

When he tries to execute a macro, nothing happens.  No error message.  Just nothing.  On further review, the macro name looks weird in the macros window.  It looks like (File Name).xlsm'!(Sheet Name).(Macro Name) instead of just listing the macro name.  Screenshot here:

[image: Macros Window - Screenshot]

The macro is a public sub sitting on the sheet. If I move the code to a module, the name displays correctly and the macro runs, but that's not the way the code was designed to function.  I'm not looking for help with the code.  (This isn't mine to change and it works fine for dozens of users.)  But I would be extremely grateful if someone familiar with this could give me an idea of what's happening here and perhaps why it could be tied to a user's corporate entitlements.

Thank you!